# Every TableView Cell has an image, some are `hidden`, how can i test if all them are not hidden?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my app, i have a table view and every row/cell has an imageView already on it. Each imageView already has its image assigned to it, each imageView's `.hidden` property is set to `YES` until otherwise specified by the user. My question is: How can i test to see if any images are `hidden`/not hidden. If 1 cell has a visible image, i want to Call a method. And if all the images are gone i want to fire a different method, Any ideas?

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
if ([self.hand.showBadge boolValue] == YES) {
    self.handView.hidden = YES;
}
else{
    self.handView.hidden = NO;
}
```

But unfortunately it didnt work.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @bill yes, sir i sure am!

Comment: updating answer below since you could just set tag for your prototype cell

Comment: Do you need to check all rows, or just all visible rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to tag the imageView w/in the cell and then use that tag to iterate over the cells as needed.

Within tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, add:

```
myImageView.tag = MY_CELL_IMAGEVIEW_TAG;
```

Alternatively, you could just set the tag for your image view in a prototype cell (or your static cells), if using storyboards.

Then, if you wanted to check the visible cells, insert the following code where you'd like to check the image views.

```
BOOL cellImageViewsAreHidden = YES;

for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
  UIImageView *cellImageView = [cell viewWithTag:MY_CELL_IMAGEVIEW_TAG];
  if ([cellImageView isHidden] == NO) {
    cellImageViewsAreHidden = NO;
    break;
  }  
}

(cellImageViewsAreHidden) ? 'method for all hidden' : 'method for not all hidden' ;
```

Comment: You should add a `break;` after `cellImageViewsAreHidden = NO;`.  He wants to call a method if "one or more" are visible, so why loop through every cell when you don't have to?

Comment: @bill okay im a little confused what `myImageView.tag = MY_CELL_IAMGEVIEW_TAG;` is? i get `myImageView.tag` but not the other part of that line of code. and how can i iterate thru every cell, not just the visible cells? And how do i add a tag? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: sorry for the confusion. MY_CELL_IMAGEVIEW_TAG would be a #define for the tag so that you don't have to use a literal in your source (e.g., add the line '#define MY_CELL_IMAGEVIEW_TAG 62' somewhere).

Comment: What action causes the imageView to change hidden state? I ask b/c you likely wouldn't need to check every cell in the table. For example, you could perform a check when tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called or when the action that changes the state is called.